# Why do these sets nest into each other in a Cantor-like fashion?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dynamical-systems, intuition

I am reading some notes on Dynamical Systems which go over the following construction. Consider
$$f(x) = \beta x(1-x)$$
where $\beta > 4$. We are interested in the set of points $\Omega$ in $[0, 1]$ which remain in $[0, 1]$ under iterations by $f$:
$$\Omega = \{x \in [0, 1]| \forall n \ge 0: f^n(x) \in {0, 1}\} = \bigcap_{n \ge 0}f^{-n}([0, 1]).$$
The graph of $f$ with $\beta = 5$ is shown below. As we can see, $f^{-1}([0, 1])$ has two components: an interval of the form $[0, a]=: I_0$ and another interval $[b, 1] =: I_1.$ Let $f_0, f_1$ be the restrictions of $f$ to $I_0, I_1$, respectively. The key observation is that for any $S \subseteq [0, 1]$ we have $f^{-1}(S) = f_0^{-1}(S)\sqcup f_1^{-1}(S)$, where  $\sqcup$ means "disjoint union."

Let $C_n = f^{-n}([0, 1])$. We have

$$\begin{align*}
C_0 &= [0, 1]\\
&\\
C_1&=I_0 \sqcup I_1\\
&\\
C_2 &= f^{-1}(I_0 \sqcup I_1) = f_0^{-1}(I_0)\sqcup f_0^{-1}(I_1) \sqcup f_1^{-1}(I_0)\sqcup f_1^{-1}(I_1)\\
&=: I_{00} \sqcup I_{01} \sqcup I_{10} \sqcup I_{11}\\
& \hspace{0.25cm} \vdots
\end{align*}$$

In general, if $B = a_0 a_1 ... a_n$ is any binary sequence, then $I_B := f_{a_0}^{-1} \circ f_{a_1}^{-1} \cdots f_{a_n}^{-1}([0, 1]).$

Now, the notes claim that the sets $C_n$ nest into each other in a Cantor-like fashion. That is, the $I_B$'s are connected components of $C_n$, and to get from $C_n$ to $C_{n+1}$ we delete a middle section of each connected component of $C_n$. However, I don't understand why this is. Could someone please explain? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Have you computed the first few $C_n$s (say, up to $n=3$)? If not, that will definitely help make the picture clearer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I did compute $C_1, C_2$, and a few intervals from $C_3$. I saw that they nest into each other like a Cantor set, but I still don't really understand why.

Comment: Make a sketch. First you mark the region $0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1$ and get two points, $0 = x_{00} < x_{01} < x_{02} < x_{03} = 1$ where the graph leaves/enters the marked region. That gives you $f^{-1}([0,1])=[0,x_{0,1}]\cup [x_{0,2},1]$. Then mark the region $\{0\leqslant y\leqslant x_{0,1}\}\cup\{x_{0,2} \leqslant y \leqslant 1\}$. You get points $0 = x_{1,0} < x_{1,1} < x_{1,2} < x_{1,3} = x_{0,0} < x_{0,2} = x_{1,4} < x_{1,5} < x_{1,6} < x_{1,7} = 1$ where the graph leaves/enters the marked region. That gives you $f^{-2}([0,1]) = [x_{1,0}, x_{1,1}] \cup \ldots \cup [x_{1,6}, x_{1,7}]$.

Comment: Then mark the region $x_{1,2k} \leqslant y \leqslant x_{1,2k+1}$ for $0 \leqslant k < 4$. You get points $0 = x_{2,0} < x_{2,1} < \ldots < x_{2,14} < x_{2,15} = 1$ where ...

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, that makes it a little more intuitive.